# How to hide admin account from other users

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, access-control, yii2-user, yii2-user-roles

I am working on `yii2`. I have some `user roles`. Admin has all the level of access. Other users have a low level of access. There is a user list which is visible to the other user. In this list all of the details of the users in the system is available. Now, I want to hide some user information from other users. The roles I want to hide are `1,6,7,8` and the role of which I want to hide is `5`. Other than the mentioned user roles should be visible to `5`. For this, I have updated the index controller.

```
 $searchModel = new UserSearch();

    $queryParams=Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    //check if user or one of the managers
    $isAdmin=in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role,[1]);

    //set params if normal user
    if(!$isAdmin){
        $queryParams['UserSearch']['user_role']=in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role,[2,3,4,5]);
    }

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
```

Now on running my project, I am only seeing the admin user. In `$queryParams['UserSearch']['user_role']=` I have tried to pass the single value of user role `5` and it does shows me only `5` role users. But I want to show the users with role `2,3,4,5`.

**Update 1**

My search model

```
class UserSearch extends User
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id','group_id'], 'integer'],
        [['email','username', 'name','contact_number','group_id','user_role'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = User::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'status' => $this->status,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'id', $this->id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'contact_number', $this->contact_number])
        ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'user_role', $this->user_role])
        ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'group_id', $this->group_id]);


   // $query->andFilterWhere(['=','user_type','user']);
    if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == Roles::ROLE_TEAM_LEAD && Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id != ''){
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=','group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id])->andWhere('user_role=4');
    }
    //$query->andFilterWhere(['!=', 'id', Yii::$app->user->id]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
 }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you intending to set `$queryParams['UserSearch']['user_role']` value to a boolean? Which is what `in_array()` will return.

Comment: No, I don't want to do that

Comment: I think that passing the array  of the user_role is not enough  .. you should che how work the filter in your searchModelsearch for manage the array  ..you passed

Comment: ad your search model

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam added

Comment: added an answer for you @MrFaisal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are changing the `index` view by using your controller? As i can see that in your search class there is already a check of `user role`.

```
 if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == Roles::ROLE_TEAM_LEAD && Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id != ''){
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=','group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id])->andWhere('user_role=4');
    }
```

After this you can add

```
if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == Roles::ROLE_INVENTORY_MANAGEMENT && Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id =='')
    {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=','group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id])->andWhere('user_role IN (2,3,4,5)');
    }
```

So your final code would be like this

```
if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == Roles::ROLE_TEAM_LEAD && Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id != ''){
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=','group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id])->andWhere('user_role=4');
    }
    else if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == Roles::ROLE_INVENTORY_MANAGEMENT && Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id =='')
    {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=','group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id])->andWhere('user_role IN (2,3,4,5)');
    }
```

I hope this also works with your filters :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @moeez bhai :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your line

```
$queryParams['UserSearch']['user_role']=in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role,[2,3,4,5]);
```

to

```
$queryParams['UserSearch']['user_role']=in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role,[2,3,4,5])?[1,6,7,8]:'';
```

and inside your search model change the condition

```
->andFilterWhere(['=', 'user_role', $this->user_role])
```

to

```
->andFilterWhere(['NOT IN', 'user_role', $this->user_role])
```

so your `search()` method will look like

```
public function search( $params ) {
    $query = User::find ();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider ( [
        'query' => $query ,
    ] );

    $this->load ( $params );

    if ( !$this->validate () ) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere ( [
        'id' => $this->id ,
        'status' => $this->status ,
    ] );

    $query->andFilterWhere ( [ 'like' , 'id' , $this->id ] )
            ->andFilterWhere ( [ 'like' , 'name' , $this->name ] )
            ->andFilterWhere ( [ 'like' , 'username' , $this->username ] )
            ->andFilterWhere ( [ 'like' , 'email' , $this->email ] )
            ->andFilterWhere ( [ 'like' , 'contact_number' , $this->contact_number ] )
            ->andFilterWhere ( [ 'NOT IN' , 'user_role' , $this->user_role ] )
            ->andFilterWhere ( [ '=' , 'group_id' , $this->group_id ] );


    // $query->andFilterWhere(['=','user_type','user']);
    if ( Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == Roles::ROLE_TEAM_LEAD && Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id != '' ) {
        $query->andFilterWhere ( [ '=' , 'group_id' , Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id ] )->andWhere ( 'user_role=4' );
    }
    //$query->andFilterWhere(['!=', 'id', Yii::$app->user->id]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If all searched model items should hide/show secure information, you can add second option to `search()` function that will show hide secure info on query building. For example:

```php
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams,
        Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role === User::ADMIN_ROLE);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

or you can add query condition at controller:

```php
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role === User::ADMIN_ROLE) {
        $dataProvider->query->andWhere(/* come condition*/);
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

If your project will use access-control at other code places, highly recommend to use [Role Based Access Control (RBAC)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac) that included at default Yii2 configuration. Using this future, you simply can check user permissions without additional columns at `user` table. It might look like this:

```php
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    if(Yii::$app->user->can(Roles::USER_VIEW_PRIVATE_INFO)) {
        $dataProvider->query->andWhere(/* come condition*/);
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```